# Send email to specific addresses based on cell value change in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Whenever a cell in column G of my spreadsheet is changed to "paid", I would like emails to be sent to the addresses contained in columns J and K on the same row, with the email subject being column A of that row, and the email message "paid"

I have seen several similar questions, but am a novice user and have trouble modifying them to suit my project needs. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(e.range.columnStart==7 && e.value.toLowerCase()=='paid' && sh.getName()=='Sheet Name') {
    var vA=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var recipient=Utilities.formatString('%s,%s', vA[9],vA[10]);
    var subject=vA[0];
    GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, 'Paid');
  }
}
```

Note: You cannot run this function from the script editor.  You will also have to update the SheetName in line 3

[Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

[Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Comment: Thanks for this, it is very much appreciated - the only way that I know of to make this work however is through the google the script editor using the sendEmailonEdit function. I have modified line 1 to:        \function sendEmailonEdit() {    to see if this works with google script editor, but get the error message: ReferenceError: "e" is not defined. (line 2, file "Code") - can you provide any more guidance? thanks again

Comment: The way I tested this was to first name it `onEdit(e)` and go to the sheet named `Sheet Name`.  I used validation on column7 and one of the options was 'paid' and I made sure that there was data in columns 1,10 and 11 of the same row.  I use `e.source.toast()`  to display messages within the script.  You can also use `Logger.log()`.  If you don't want to name it onEdit(e) or if you're trying to something that requires permission then you will have to use an installable trigger which you can install manually or with code and assign that trigger to the new function name.