# Send specific email when cell is changed

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

So I have a form and collects emails.
In the spreadsheet contains Status column (C) data validation: Not started,In progress, Pending, Closed

I am very new to Google Sheets scripting, so if the status (C) column on a row is changed to Closed. Email is sent to the corresponding email address on Email Column (E).

"Your ticket has been resolved" etc. something in that manner.
Like I said, I am new to programming (javascript) if anyone can help, would appreciate it

```
Timestamp              _UID          Status        Name     Email Address
6/12/2020 0:47:28   Ticket-21228    Not Started Stan Smith  abc@gmail.com
6/12/2020 0:51:21   Ticket-60128    Closed      John Smith  zxy@gmail.com
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Comment: Take a look on [Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions), **a simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail service requires authorization**

Comment: Hi @Cooper, My apologies as I am still very new to coding, (rusty to be exact). 
basically I ran into your reply in a different thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58275064/send-email-to-specific-addresses-based-on-cell-value-change-in-google-sheets , But cells changed to closed on Column C, then the email address is at Column E on the same row.
I modified your reply and triggers are working. Just that I am not receiving the emails. (Not a permission issue as the other trigger (onFormSubmit) that I have set up worked).
My apologies if I am being new.

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you want.  If you would create an example may be I could figure it out.  Or provide me with and image of what you have and what you want.  Don't bother giving me a link to spreadsheet because I wont click on it.

Comment: @Cooper I understand, I updated my question with an image.
If Column C is changed to "Closed", send an email on the same row using the email address in Column E.

Comment: Okay I understand.  Now do me a favor and copy those three line of spreadsheet and paste it into you question so that I don't have to copy all that text okay?

Comment: Question updated @Cooper

Comment: Okay I think I'll  let you test it for me.  Now you can't run this like other function because it requires an event object.  If you want to run this manual from the script editor you have to create all of the event object parameters that you are using.  I do this often myself and it's not that hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to be a installable trigger because it uses Gmail which requires permission.
You need to add the sheet name and the message for the email

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry');
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=="Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart==3 && e.value=="Closed") {
    let vA=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var body=Utilities.formatString('You create this')
    GmailApp.sendEmail(vA[4], vA[5], body);  
  }
}
```

So you can probably test it directly with something like this:

```
function testMyOnEdit() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rg=sh.getRange(3,3);
  let e={range:{columnStart:3,rowStart:3},source:ss,value:'Closed'};
  e.range=rg;
  onMyEdit(e);
}
```

Don't forget to delete the trigger when you do this.